# Trying to read data from a excel file gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

I have added the poi-bin-3.9-20121203 jar to my Eclipse Java Project.

This is my java code

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;



import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.*;

public class Exce 
{
public static void main(String argds[]) throws InvalidFormatException,FileNotFoundException, IOException{


        FileInputStream fis;

            fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Sample.xlsx");
            Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            String un=wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String pw=wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println("Value 1 : " + un);
            System.out.println("Value 2 :" + pw); 

            }

}
```

it is giving me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:72)
    at Exce.main(Exce.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions
```

Can anyone help me how this can be solved

Comment: Looks like the jar cannot be found when the application is executed. Make sure to add the poi libraries in your classpath when executing your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) jar to your project.